# How to create an auto increment seed in in python , making a heads or tails game?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've ended up with this code but I don't want to create a seed number on my own and want to by created by python:

```
 import random   
 test_seed = int(input("Create a seed number"))   
 random.seed(test_seed)   
 random_side = random.randint(0, 1)   
 if random_side == 1:   
     print("Heads")  
 else:
     print("Tails")
```

See if you can help me!

Comment: By default the random number generator uses the current system time. You can use `random.seed()` without arguments.

Comment: Why are you creating the seed at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can auto-increment the seed by not supplying the seed at all.

Instead of:
`random.seed(test_seed)`

Use:
`random.seed()`

This will give you a seed based on the system time and thus would increment automatically(unless time stops for some reason).